# Expo XDE for Windows hangs when i create a new project as react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, exponent, expo

11:19:13 PM
Starting React Native packager...
11:19:21 PM
Scanning 535 folders for symlinks in C:\data\TodoList\tasklist\node_modules (16ms)
11:19:21 PM
Loading dependency graph.
11:19:21 PM
Running packager on port 19001.
11:19:21 PM
11:19:38 PM
Dependency graph loaded.

when i create new project i get the aforesaid on console and then it hangs ? is there any prerequisits for this to run why i may have not installed ?

i assumed its the virus guard because kaspersky prompted a warning, but it still hangs even after the disabled it [the virus guard].

Comment: I've had the same problem, I suppose it is a bug.

Comment: Same issue here, however, I found some temporary workarounds to avoid wasting time on that. elaborated [in this link](https://exhesham.com/2017/12/06/overcoming-expo-xde-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by this all. following are all required and after installing them expo-xde started.

1)Disable secure boot in BIOS

2)Enable Virtualization in BIOS.

3)Reinstalled Expo-XDE

4)Installed  Python and JDK which is required according to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#node-python2-jdk)

5)Installed react-native [cli using npm.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli.html)

Restart your machine now.

6)Even if this doesn't work then install [Genymotion](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/genymotion.html)  as Android virtual device API-23 Marshmello, which comes with by-default Expo app and you can run `npm run android` [from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WUrW.png) and enter url in Expo app in Genymotion.

complete steps of Genymotion(step 6), I followed from [here](https://medium.com/@devmrin/complete-how-to-create-react-native-app-with-genymotion-android-emulator-on-windows-10-in-10-3834fd90b074).

---